# How do you refer to a Java Class in the same Package from a Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I am starting Clojure development in Eclipse

I have a new package called *"apackage"* under src.

In it I have JavaClass.java and Test.clj.
How do I call the constructor of the JavaClass from the clojure file?

I tried

```
   (def a (new apackage.JavaClass))
```

but I am getting a *ClassNotFoundException*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem.
The Clojure file didnt have a namespace defined

I added (ns apackage).

Answer (score 0):

That is how you do it.

I have Clojuredev install in Eclipse 3.5 and what you described above just worked.

Perhaps you have misspelled something or your classpath isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

could be an issue with the :gen-class keyword in your name space deffinition.